# Using a variable in shell script and running as a cron job

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, sh

I have the following script dbbackup.sh

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -h 436543545.amazonaws.com -u admin--password=goaway mydb > dump-1.sql
s3cmd put dump-1.sql s3://database-blah-bucket
rm -f -r dump-1.sql
```

I need to make the following changes

1. The file to be in the following format (dump-1.sql) is to be `dump-dd-mm-yyy-hh-mm.sql`
2. Running the script by `sh dbbackup.sh` which I need to run as a cron job everyday at 3am

Completely new to UNIX so not sure how to do above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of `dbbackup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="436543545.amazonaws.com"
PORT=3306
USER="admin"
PASSWORD="goaway"
DATABASE="mydb"

DATE_STR=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M)

FILENAME="dump-${DATE_STR}.sql

mysqldump -P $PORT -h $HOST -u $USER --password=${PASSWORD} $DATABASE > $FILENAME
s3cmd put $FILENAME s3://database-blah-bucket
rm -f -r $FILENAME
```

Then go into crontab using `crontab -e`. Enter:

```
0 3 * * *  /path/to/dbbackup.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `date` command, see the following `shell` code :

```
dump="dump-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M).sql"
mysqldump -P 3306 -h 436543545.amazonaws.com -u admin--password=goaway mydb > "$dump"
s3cmd put "$dump" s3://database-blah-bucket
rm -f -r "$dump"
```